# mount -t cifs fails with permission denied

Tags: debian, mount, cifs, volume

I have a Windows 10 share for a particular user. Then I have Debian:stretch in a docker container. I try to mount a shared folder like this:

```
root@b9cda19f784c:~# mount -t cifs -v -o username=dockerfile,password=docker,sec=ntlm //10.0.75.1/hlds /root/somedir
mount: permission denied
```

I tried to remove `sec=ntlm` option, set `uid` and `gid` in options but didn't succeed. Also I don't see any verbose messages that I'm expecting of `-v` flag.

From my Windows 10 host I can mount this folder using a command:

```
net use p: \\10.0.75.1\hlds /user:dockeruser
```

How can I make `mount` command output more information to debug? Or what am I missing in my `mount` command?

**UPDATE**

Running a container with `--privileged` flag doesn't help:

```
root@62d77b4c1058:/# mount -v -t cifs -o username=dockerfile,password=docker //10.0.75.1/hlds /root/mnt 
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.75.1,unc=\\10.0.75.1\hlds,user=dockerfile,pass=******** 
mount error(13): Permission denied 
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

And creating a volume using Docker and mounting it didn't succeed:

```
PS F:\repos\hlds-docker> docker volume create --opt type=cifs --opt device=//10.0.75.1/hlds --opt o=username=dockerfile,password=docker,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=0,gid=0 myvolume
myvolume
PS F:\repos\hlds-docker> docker run --rm -v myvolume:/root -it --privileged debian:stretch bash
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume with options: type='cifs' device='//10.0.75.1/hlds' o='username=dockerfile,password=docker,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=0,gid=0': permission denied.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

My Docker Version:

```
PS F:\repos\hlds-docker> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:34:26 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:41:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 1):

So after some trials and tributations I found a solution (but I think it's weird).
You need to do 2 steps:

1. Put some dummy file in your dir so it's not empty (either way you get `permission denied` error)
2. Create docker volume with `noserverino` option (found accidentally)

So in my case it's:

```
docker volume create --opt type=cifs --opt device=//10.0.75.1/hlds --opt o=username=dockeruser,password=docker,noserverino,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000 somevol
```

And then:

```
docker run --rm -v somevol:/home/steam/opts -it krow7/hlds:1.0 bash
```

So you have your dirs owned by an exact user you need and can do all operations with files on a mounted share.

I hope someone will find it useful.